# Проблема с редактированием модуля в Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

Собственно видео - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTJkVhj8BKs&feature=youtu.be

Как корректно отредактировать блок?

Comment: После просмотра видео, самый интригующий вопрос - как показывает на сайте модуль который отключён в админке? 
Вы что то не "допоказываете",  самодельный напиленный шаблон?

Comment: @Arsen Там просто существует другой модуль, что включает данный блок. Вот что будет когда включить -  youtu.be/EtiOtkXx_l8

Comment: если честно, второе видео непонятно было... вы можете показать код  index.php а точнее кусок кода где имеется данная позиция для модуля, потом вы не сказали это купленный шаблон или самодельный?

Comment: @Arsen я ниже еще написал + видео.

Comment: Поместите вопрос в тело вопроса.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После анализа данных, первая мысль что приходит,по всей вероятности у вас проблемы с редактором, возможно после сохранения, редактор вносит какие то изменения в html коде тем самым вся вёрстка портиться.

1. Можете,до изменения,попробовать скопировать код в редактор там поменять цену и после весь код вставить в редактор.
2. Можете сравнить код - до и после сохранения в редакторе.
3. Можете попробовать сменить редактор, в глобальных настройках Joomla, на другой редактор и снова сохранить изменения в модуле.

Comment: Вот еще - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CAotgG52dDQ Шаблон платный, с рутрекера) Я уже поставил другой редактор - JCE, все тоже самое

Comment: @LitaLitar в любом случае просмотрев видео вам не помочь!  вы все делаете верно, никаких проблем я не вижу НО! для того чтобы помочь мне надо посмотреть html + css вашего сайта, до и после сохранения.
Если есть возможность - дайте ссылку на сайт, если нет, то вам придётся просмотреть строение и стили данного блока html в браузере.Как работать с дебагером, можете прочитать тут  https://www.templatemonster.com/help/ru/use-google-chrome-web-inspector.html
ЗЫ  если шаблон платный, вы може обратиться к разработчику для исправления данного дефекта

Comment: вот сайт - h96637fx.beget.tech

Comment: Хорошо, я посмотрел, теперь сможешь сделать изменения в модуле, чтобы вёрстка 'сломалась' и я посмотрю в чём разница.По той же ссылке сделай изменения в модуле

Comment: сделал уже изменения в 2 блоках

Comment: @LitaLitar я проверил, диагноз ясен )) даже был предсказуем.
Данный шаблон "варезный",. его использовать не советую т.к в нём чужеродные ссылки и возможно многое другое! 
http://prnt.sc/dxar79

Comment: Что касается проблемы с блоками тоже обнаружил, в шаблоне по всей вероятности мини защита есть, т.е возможно при изменении контента, меняется строение сайта тем самым всё разрушается!!
http://prnt.sc/dxarf0 до изменения строение HTML  идёт так

.pricing ul .pricing-table-wrapper li.head

а после изменения http://prnt.sc/dxarko  на сайте меняется расположение и последовательность структуры

.pricing .pricing-table-wrapper ul li.head

для работы после изменения, вам надо ручным методом проверить всю иерархию стилей и поменять в css файле  - что конечно не целесобразно ))

Comment: ясно, буду искать другой, спасибо Вам за консультацию. Если можно еще один общий  вопрос, есть к примеру тот сайт (шаблон), и ставлю нужный мне плагин, после чего на главной - шапка и подвал сохраняются, а все другие блоки и модули исчезают. Не подскажите куда копать? На сайте плагин включил (проверял на другом шаблоне - тоже самое).

Comment: Что за плагин? как называется? возможно при активации плагина, из за каких то несовместимостей, возникает внутренняя ошибка (php error) при котором уже загрузка фреймворка прерывается.Такие проблемы в основном встречаются у контентных плагинов. Также проблема может быть скрыта именно в Joomla, если его 'перелапатили' незнающие мастера )))
Можно попробовать посмотреть error.log в корне сайта.

Comment: вот - https://github.com/active-programming/mycityselector Мне просто очень нужна модель выбора города, з разными ценами на сайт. Данный шаблон, единственное, что нашел. В error.log ничего нету

Comment: Понятно, врятли будет возможность Вам помочь, т.к возможных проблем будет очень много, и проверить это всё дистанционно невозможно.
Если Вы уверенны что всё правильно установили, настроили и у вас система Joomla >= 3.3.0 и   PHP >= 5.5, Вы можете написать разработчику и описать проблему  https://github.com/adamasantares
думаю он более быстро даст ответ от чего такое может быть ))

Comment: ясно спасибо. Буду дальше сам розбираться и искать другой шаблон